# Docker ngrok container with another container app. How to connect?

Tags: docker

Im trying to connect ngrok with my webapp

When I start ngrok container with my app docker id

```
sudo docker run --rm -it wernight/ngrok ngrok http dfe68e946200:8000
```

nothing happens

if I start

```
sudo docker run --rm -it wernight/ngrok ngrok http localhost:8000
```

I'm always getting bad gateway

If Im doing everything without docker containers everything works.

Is there any solution that ngrok container could talk with my webapp container? I opened port 8000 in my container webapp

I found till now only a one solution:

I need to get ip address of my container and start ngrok like this:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it wernight/ngrok ngrok http 172.17.0.4:8000
```

but I dont like this solution :( because it takes to long time. Is there any other easier way?

Comment: Try using container name instead of localhost. In your case, it will be ngrok

Comment: but it makes no sense ;) I want to have 2 containers: 1. ngrok and 2. my webapp. Ngrok forwards all requests to my 2. container webapp

Comment: I get the same result as @AnnaK. If I use my internal ip address of my router, it works.

Answer (score 2):

The standard docker way for connecting containers is docker networks.
Create a docker network and connect both containers to it.

```
sudo docker network create mynet
sudo docker network connect mynet <app-container-name>
sudo docker run --network mynet --rm -it wernight/ngrok ngrok http <app-container-name>:<internal-app-container-port>
```

When the containers are connected to the same network, they can connect to each other using the container name as a hostname.

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway